# How to temporarily remove (not delete and replace) Tkinter widget without using just .place?

Tags: python, tkinter

I hope this isn't a duplicate but I could not find this anywhere:

I have been using Tkinter for application writing for awhile (even 2 games in it, but I use Pygame for that now.)

My question is, **how would I do** a ".pack" then ".unpack" ( remove temporarily ) without using a dirty trick of "`.place( x = someLARGE_Number, y = anotherLARGE_Number )`"

Ex:
    root = Tk()

```
root.geometry( "300x300" )
root.title( "Test" )

label1 = Label( root, text = "Hi" )
label1.place( x = 1, y = 1 )

root.mainloop()
```

and when I remove it temp. I type something like:

```
label1.place( x = 3333, y = 3333 )
```

I know pack and unpack exist, but you can't unpack an object that has been placed nor can you place an item precisely using pack so how would I remove it neater? It looks gross on code and probably placing a lot of stuff away or on screen sometimes can be barely seen move 1 at a time. If this is a duplicate, please comment something to help, but I could not find something like it.

**Restatement:**

**PROBLEM:** Clean way to temporarily remove an item, without destroying it or using a .place() method with a pair of large, offscreen, numbers.

**TRIED:** `.place( x = LARGE, y = LARGE )` and that's it, .unpack requires something to be .pack(ed) and you can't (from what I know) place items where you want via .pack.

**NEED:** Help or a link to an answered question like mine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `.place_forget()` method, that is associated with the type of a "*geometry-manager*" your have selected when the widget was created:

```
label1.place_forget()
```

After that, you can make it appear again by placing it again:

```
label1.place(x=1, y=1)
```

Just note that it's not always beneficial to use the `.place() / .place_forget()` geometry manager.

You may also use `.grid() / .grid_forget()` or `.pack() / .pack_forget()` methods for other geometry managers, where grid-arrangement or pack-layout fits better your GUI-setup/configuration/resizing needs.

One may inspect doc-string attributes `.__doc__` for all the instance-methods:

```
>>> print label.place_forget.__doc__
Unmap this widget.
>>> print label.grid_forget.__doc__
Unmap this widget.
>>> print label.pack_forget.__doc__
Unmap this widget and do not use it for the packing order.
```

Comment: I think you may of messed up but "place geometry manager. Use grid or place" did you make "Use grid or pack"? And if so, how would I place it accurately (AKA using coordinates?)

Comment: Yes, I meant `pack` and `grid`. Additionally, those are introducing entirely other systems that don't rely on coordinates. These are more flexible and easier to use for complex and resizable content. Read more about them [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm).

Answer (score -1):

You can inquire as to whether a widget is "mapped" with a geometry manager (*grid*, *pack*, or *place*) and then "forget" it as needed:

```
def unmap(widget):
    result = False
    if widget and widget.winfo_exists() and widget.winfo_ismapped():
        result = True
        geom_mgr = widget.winfo_manager()
        if geom_mgr == 'grid':
            widget.grid_forget()
        elif geom_mgr == 'pack':
            widget.pack_forget()
        elif geom_mgr == 'place':
            widget.place_forget()
        else:
            result = False
    return result
```

Note that calling a "forget" routine that does not match the mapping routine does not throw an exception. So, if you `pack()` a widget, you can call `grid_forget()` on that widget without causing an error or having any effect. In that case, only `pack_forget()` would hide the widget.